# Looking for a Linux application for programmatically panning and zooming over particular portions of an A0 poster

Tags: linux, pdf, programming, presentation, slideshow

I have to create a lot of A0/A1 posters for my job, and I usually do this by producing a PDF and printing it.  The problem is that I also have to produce a separate slideshow presentation.

Rather than doing these two things separately, I'd like to start re-using the poster for the presentation.  Of course, slideshows are expected in presentations, and A0 would be too small to present to a full room.

So I want a PDF viewer application that can be programmed to smoothly pan between different parts of a PDF.  I.e. it might begin at the top over the title, author and email addresses. Then when I hit space, I will have previously programmed where to go next in the PDF.  The projected display would then perform a smooth transition between the current position over the poster and the next position.

This would be a similar style of presentation to those you can do with Prezi.  I can't use Prezi however, as it's missing too many of the features I need.